# C program doesn't see last letter at .txt file

Tags: c

This code basically creates a txt file and add names and if users inputs new name it adds to txt file but it doesn't see the last letter like jack -> jac . Btw it saves names perfectly in txt file. So issue has to be at `dosyaOku()` .This informations must be enough but thanks to stackoverflow I need to add some more details.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


char allFile[1000][100],userName[100];
int i = 0;

int main()
{
    addSomeNames();
    dosyaOku();
    isimAl();
    isimKarsilastir();
    dosyaOku();
    return 0;
}
void isimKarsilastir()
{
    int a,ayni = 0;
    for (a=0 ; a < i; a++)
    {
        if (strcmp(allFile[a],userName) == 0)
        {
            printf("ayni\n");
            ayni++;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("farkli\n");
        }
    }
    if (ayni>0)
    {
        printf("Kullanici adi bulunmustur\n");
    }
    else
    {
        dosyaYaz();
    }
}
void dosyaYaz()
{
    FILE * ptrfile;
    ptrfile = fopen("sondokunus.txt","a");
    fprintf(ptrfile,"\n%s",userName);
    fclose(ptrfile);

}
void isimAl()
{

    printf("Isim giriniz: ");
    gets(userName);
    printf("Girdiginiz isim: %s",userName);


}
void dosyaOku()
{

    FILE *ptrfile = NULL;
    int *ptri;
    ptri = &i;
    *ptri = 0;
    int top = 0;

    ptrfile = fopen("sondokunus.txt", "r");
    while(fgets(allFile[*ptri], 100, ptrfile))
    {
        allFile[*ptri][strlen(allFile[*ptri]) - 1] = '\0';
        *ptri += 1;
    }
    top = *ptri;
    printf("\n Dosyadaki isimler: \n");
    for(*ptri = 0; *ptri < top; *ptri += 1)
    {
        printf("%s\n", allFile[*ptri]);
    }
    fclose(ptrfile);
}
void addSomeNames()
{
    FILE * ptrfile;
    ptrfile = fopen("sondokunus.txt", "w+");
    char names[100][100];
    strcpy(names[0],"mike");
    strcpy(names[1],"joe");
    strcpy(names[2],"jack");
    for (int n=0;n <= 2; n++)
    {
        fprintf(ptrfile,"\n%s", names[n]);
    }
    fclose(ptrfile);

}
```

Comment: [Never use `gets`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: If the last line of your input file doesn't end with a newline character, then `allFile[*ptri][strlen(allFile[*ptri]) - 1] = '\0';` will delete the last character that it does contain.  And indeed that is what happens because `addSomeNames` prints the newline before the name instead of after.

Comment: As Nate pointed out, you're creating the file by putting the newline before the name. I'd fix that. But, _some_ `.txt` files omit the newline for the last line. A more certain way to strip an [possibly] optional newline is: `allFile[*ptri][strlen(allFile[*ptri]) - 1] = '\0';` --> `allFile[*ptri][strcspn(allFile[*ptri],"\n")] = '\0';`

Comment: _Side note:_ Using `*ptri` is an unnecessary complication. You can replace all `*ptri` with just `i`. And, in this particular function, `i` doesn't need to be global [AFAICT]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Code has at least::

`allFile[*ptri][strlen(allFile[*ptri]) - 1] = '\0';` as a problem.

When the *string* at  `allFile[*ptri]` does not end with a `"\n"` (fairly common due to reading the last line in a text file), it lops off a non-`'\n'` character.

Instead

```
size_t length_of_string_without_linefeed = strcspn(allFile[*ptri], "\n");
allFile[*ptri][length_of_string_without_linefeed] = '\0';
// or
allFile[*ptri][strcspn(allFile[*ptri], "\n")] = '\0';
```

---

`allFile[*ptri][strlen(allFile[*ptri]) - 1]` is hacker exploitable.

If the first character in a *line* from the file is a *null character*, then code is like:

```
allFile[*ptri][(size_t)0 - 1]
// or 
allFile[*ptri][SIZE_MAX]
```

Which leads to *undefined behavior*.

Do not use `- 1` with `strlen(allFile[*ptri]) - 1` when `strlen(allFile[*ptri]) == 0`.

Answer (score 1):

Further to [chux's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67234264/451601) answer, I would use instead:

```
char *p = strchr( allFile[*ptri], '\n' );
if( p ) *p = '\0';
```

That makes abundantly clear what you're doing, and doesn't rely on overwriting the NUL terminator if the newline isn't present.

Comment: This is another, and correct approach. Note:  `line[strcspn(line, "\n\r")]=0;` can be used to lop off those pesky various end-of-lines like `'\n'`,  `\r'`, `'\r\n'`, etc. that come from other systems' text formats.

Answer (score 0):

As noted in other answers, `dosyaOku` behaves incorrectly if it gets a line that doesn't end in `\n`, and you should fix that.  But the reason your file looks like that in the first place is probably a separate bug in `addSomeNames`.  You have

```
        fprintf(ptrfile,"\n%s", names[n]);
```

with the newline printed before the name.  This means the file will begin with a blank line, and the last line will not have `\n` at the end.  You probably wanted to write:

```
        fprintf(ptrfile,"%s\n", names[n]);
```